# many FunctionTransformer to the same column - sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I have only one input, which is email of a user and i create many different functions to create features from the email using  `FunctionTransformers` from [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/0.23/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer), example

```
X = np.array(['aaaaa@gmail.com', 'sdfsadf@yahoo.com'])
y = np.array([True, False])

def email_length(email) -> np.array:
    return [len(e.split('@')[0]) for e in email]

def domain_length(email) -> np.array:
    return [len(e.split('@')[-1]) for e in email]

def number_of_vouls(email) -> np.array:
    vouls = 'aeiouAEIOU'
    name = [e.split('@')[0] for e in email]
    return [sum(1 for char in name if char in vouls) for name in name]
```

after creating the functions i pack it in the `FunctionTransformers`

```
email_length1 = FunctionTransformer(email_length)
domain_length1 = FunctionTransformer(domain_length)
number_of_vouls1 = FunctionTransformer(number_of_vouls)
```

Then i create the Pipeline

```
pipe = Pipeline([
        ('email_length', email_length1),
        ('domain_length', domain_length1),
        ('number_of_vouls', number_of_vouls1),
        ('classifier', LGBMClassifier())
        ])
```

But when i try to fit the model like

```
 pipe.fit(X, y)
```

I have `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'` but whenever i do

```
domain_length(X)
Output : [9, 9]
```

Comment: I do not get that error (I get different ones instead); please check that your supplied code matches what you're running, and provide the full error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Pipeline steps are applied sequentially, so your second transformer is receiving the email lengths rather than the email addresses.

You can use a `ColumnTransformer` or `FeatureUnion` here.  For example,

```py
preproc = FeatureUnion([
        ('email_length', email_length1),
        ('domain_length', domain_length1),
        ('number_of_vouls', number_of_vouls1),
])

pipe = Pipeline([
        ('preproc', preproc),
        ('classifier', LGBMClassifier())
        ])
```

You'll get a new error because of the shape of the returns in your functions, but wrapping those up to numpy arrays and shaping them appears to work:

```py
def email_length(email) -> np.array:
    return np.array([len(e.split('@')[0]) for e in email]).reshape(-1, 1)
```